# Strictly Non-expansive Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is a Banach space, the strictly nonexpansive linear operator $T$ satisfy the following: $$\Vert Tx-Ty \Vert < \Vert x - y \Vert$$ If $ \text{dim} X < \infty \quad$ can we prove that   $ \forall x \in X \quad  \lim_{n\to \infty} T^{n}x=0$, i.e., $x=0$ is a fixed point of $T$?

Comment: what do you think the word "linear" means?

Comment: @Action can you give an example of a linear operator that satisfies $T(0) \neq 0$? Or I guess, more generally, $T^n(0) \neq 0$ for some $n$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I think op meant $0$ is the **only** fixed point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $X$ is finite dimensional, then closed balls are compact and $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Tx\| <1$. Now, either by submultiplicativity or  by Banach fixed point theorem, we obtain that $T^n x \to 0$ for any $x\in X$.

Comment: Yes sure any closed balls in finite dimensional Banach space $X$ are compact. Does it directly help to show that if  $T:X \Rightarrow X$ is strictly nonexpansive linear operator then for any $x \in X$ $\quad \lim_{n\to \infty} T^{n}x=0$

Comment: @Action yes, as $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\| < 1$.

Comment: The problem is that I do not see this convergence to 0, based on the argument of compactness of the ball.

Comment: @Action I expanded the answer.